# C#, how to halve a byte array?

Tags: c#

I have a byte array defined like this

```
byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(zfoFileName);
```

How can I get the first 1/2 of the fileContents byte array?

In other words if the upper bound of the array is 10, I would like a new byte array to have the first 5 values of fileContents.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jason that is a very good question

Comment: sounds like you want to read using a buffer, ReadAllBytes should only be used when you want to, umm well, Read All Bytes

Answer (score 7):

```
byte[] half = new byte[fileContents.Length / 2];
Array.Copy(fileContents, half, half.Length);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Array.Resize(ref fileContents, fileContents.Length / 2);
```

Better to only read the first half in the first place, though.

Comment: As I read the question, he wants a new array with half the bytes.

Comment: @Brian - which is *exactly* what that does (hence `ref`). You can't *really* resize an array, after all. He didn't say anything about a new *variable*...

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I guess you could read it either way. I was under the impression that he wanted a new variable as well, but hopefully he'll clarify. Anyway, Resize is a good option so +1 from me.

Answer (score 5):

```
var firstHalf = fileContents.Take(fileContents.Length / 2).ToArray();
```

Comment: That is possibly the most expensive way I can think of... fine for the proposed 10 bytes, but for 10MB?

Comment: @Marc: I like your way, this was the first thing I thought of. About to look up Array methods when everyone else popped up. Although I'm sure you can think of a more expensive way.

Comment: More expensive? Needs more xml... ;-p

Answer (score 5):

why not to read sequentially bytes from file? You can read just a half. You do unneeded operations.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with LINQ or the Array class:

```
var half = fileContents.Take(fileContents.Length / 2);
// ---
var half = new byte[fileContents.Length / 2];
Array.Copy(fileContents, half, fileContents.Length / 2)
```

But you should rather go for manually reading data from a FileStream because with the upper code you read all data from the file even though you just need half of it.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    var half = reader.ReadBytes(stream.Length / 2);
}
```

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more correct way to read half a file into a single `byte[]`:

```
byte[] data;
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(zfoFileName)) {
    int len = (int)fs.Length / 2, bytesRead, offset = 0;
    data = new byte[len];
    while(len > 0 && (bytesRead = fs.Read(data, offset, len)) > 0) {
        len -= bytesRead;
        offset += bytesRead;
    }
    if (len > 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
}
// now look at data
```

In short, it simply reads half the data, in as few operations as possible, but catering for the fact that `Stream.Read` doesn't guarantee to read all the data you ask for each time.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
byte[] halfFileContents = new byte[Math.Floor(filecontents.Length / 2)];
Arra.Copy(fileContents, halfFileContents, halfFileContents.Lenght);
```

If you don't need fileContents in the first place, you can use FileStream and BinaryReader, and read only half of the file into the array.

Comment: `.Length / 2` is integer arithmetic. No need to `Floor`, which would btw return `double` or `float`, and you can't use `new byte[]` with that.